# How can I check and save text from span element

Tags: gatling

I have been trying to get the text out of a span element without much success.
using the following:

```
.check(css("span[id='hostName']", "text").saveAs("__HOST")))
```

but it does not find the text.

this is the html

```
<span id="hostName" style="padding:0">01</span>
```

can i do this with css checker or do i have to resort to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct quote from the [Gatling documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/http/http_check.html?highlight=css):

> css(expression, attribute)
>
> expression can be a plain String, a String using Gatling EL or an Expression[String].
>
> attribute is an optional String.
>
> When filled, check is performed against the attribute value. Otherwise check is performed against the node text content.